# How many times can Proxima Cenatauri Scholars use its owner benefit?

Tags: alien-frontiers

I am a bit confused about the owner benefit for Proxima Cenatauri Scholars.

The Scholars may not place or removemore than one field generator per turn. Does this mean :

a) the Scholars can only place one generator, or remove one generator - ie use the benefit only once per turn

OR

b) the Scholars can remove and place a generator as many times as they like, as long as it is the same generator each time? eg pay 6 fuel,  place the repulsor on the Rev to get an agenda victory point, remove the repulsor, then place it on another territory?

Thanks very much

Comment: I don't know the game at all, but option "B" seems *very* unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is Option A: you may make one placement or removal (not both) per turn. Your suggestion of spending 6 fuel to score an agenda is quite creative, and almost certainly not anticipated by the designers – there's normally no benefit at all for moving a single field generator multiple times (except, I suppose, to destroy the Relic Ship with the Isolation Field).

I do not have any specific rules text to back me up, but the Alien Frontiers rules are intended to be as straightforward as possible and allow useful, but not crazy, interactions. There are a handful of weird combinations that were not prohibited by the rules, but were disallowed in later errata. Here's a few examples:

1. Ain't no rule that says you can't use the Plasma Cannon's discard power to destroy a player's fourth ship while they have one ship sitting on the Terraforming Station (and thus they'll be down to two ships on their turn).
2. Ain't no rule that says the ships on the Raider's Outpost matter if you remove one with a Plasma Cannon.
3. Ain't no rule that says you can't discard the Plasma Cannon to destroy a player's third ship when they also own the Relic Ship. (Have you noticed that the Plasma Cannon has the most weird interactions?)

The point is, you get full points for creativity, but you're stretching the spirit of the rules pretty badly and that's exactly the kind of thing that gets errata'd in Alien Frontiers. The creators run an Errata thread over on BoardGameGeek, if you'd like to ask them directly: http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/572710/rule-book-errata/page/2

(My logical fallacy is: Appeal To Authority. I've played Alien Frontiers with Randall Bart, the designer of the Alien Frontiers: Outer Belt expansion and early playtester of Alien Frontiers.)

Comment: Thanks Paul! I thought it would be A. I asked the same question on boardgamegeek http://boardgamegeek.com/article/16943412#16943412 and Michael from Game Salute confirmed it too. The plasma cannon is interesting for sure. Discarding it to destroy someone else's ship is a line we haven't crossed yet in our games - we try to be as skulduggerous as possible but for some reason we made a decision early on that taking out someone else's ship is going too far. One day I'm sure we'll bring it into play, but no-one wants to be the first to do it! Hamish